# New properties file in JHipster not working

Tags: spring, jhipster

First of all, I understand there is the ApplicationProperties created by JHipster to use. But for testing purpose, I created the following:

**Class TestProperties**

```
package com.xxx.yyy.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class TestProperties {

    private String dummyValue;

    public String getDummyValue() {
        return dummyValue;
    }

    public void setDummyValue(String dummyValue) {
        this.dummyValue = dummyValue;
    }

}
```

**Class TestService**

```
package com.xxx.yyy.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.xxx.yyy.config.TestProperties;

@Service
public class TestService {

     private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

     private final TestProperties testProperties;

     public TestService(TestProperties testProperties) {
         this.testProperties = testProperties;
     }

     public void test() {
         log.debug("show have val" + testProperties.getDummyValue());
     }
}
```

In application-dev.yml, I have

```
# application:

test:
    dummy-value: Test Value
```

However when I run mvn, I get the following error, anybody know what is wrong?

```
DEBUG 10760 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Close successful.
ERROR 10760 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.xxx.yyy.service.TestService required a bean of type 'com.xxx.yyy.config.TestProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.yyy.config.TestProperties' in your configuration.
```

I understand that since Spring 4.3, there is no need for the annotation for @Autowired and if any arguments of the constructor are Spring beans. I tested with JHipsterProperties in my service and it works.

```
 public TestService(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties ) {
     this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
 }
```

Anybody knows why my new properties does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the properties to be loaded, you need to add it to `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in your application's main class.  For the jhipster-sample-app, [it would be added here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/a9b789f832b3bc508721605a66fb72e2e8edd01d/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/JhipsterSampleApplicationApp.java#L22).

Comment: Thanks! I search JHipsterProperties in my source and did not find anything. But another qn, why did JHipsterProperties work even though it is not specified in @EnableConfigurationProperties?

Comment: That's configured in the jhipster Java library here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/blob/7a8e670f96bf224708d3f23c51e1b241bef97d23/jhipster-framework/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories